# Section loop starts with wrong index/value

Tags: smarty

I`d like to fill a select box for year of birth with the years starting with the current year -18 and then 100 years backwards. Somehow the loop starts with 2000 and not 2001.

When I use the smarty.now funtion and substract 18 years from it, it will result in 2001 which is correct.

But when I use the same function in a section loop and step -1, the loop will start with 2000 and not 2001.

I could use -17 in the section loop but I`d like to understand why there seems to be an offset of 1 here even if the default value for start is 0 according to the documentation.

```
{$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y"-18}
{*  Result is 2001 as expected *}
<br>
{section name=bar loop=$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y"-18 max=100 step=-1}
{$smarty.section.bar.index}
{/section}
{*  Loop starts with 2000,1999... why? *}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in your `date_format` , you put `step = -1` .

Smarty execute this step in the section before displaying the first value. So, the section will be like that :

2000
1999
1998
..

Comment: Thank you. So step-1 will always be executed before the output of the first value? Hm, that doesn`t make sense to me. It seems I really have to change it to -17 to get the right values.

Comment: Yes, I use it if one of my project, it's stupid but it's like that and I don't know an other solution for that . I think also it's always with -1 in the reverse sens, also if you put step=-2. It's note like that in the smarty documentation of {section}